# Airflow Metadata using Rest api

Tags: airflow

I’m using Airflow version 2.6.3 and familiar with using the rest api to extract useful metadata but want to instead execute this from within Airflow and across our other AWS environments. I then want to highlight the differences when benchmarked against our 1 production instance.

Welcome to other suggestions.

I’ve tried using the SimpleHttpOperator but only works with cookies ie cannot using basic auth. `

If outside I run this

```
import requests
from icecream import ic

url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/config'

with requests.sessions.Session() as session:
    session.auth = ("admin", "test")
    session.headers.update({'Accept': 'application/json'})
    # session.verify = False

    # r = session.get(url, cookies=cookies, verify=False) # WORKS
    r = session.get(url, verify=False)

    ic(r.status_code)
```

it keeps erroring with 401 and **only works with a cookie**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`@task` decorated function](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html#tasks) (or a plain old [PythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html)) and just use the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to interact with the [Airflow REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html) from a DAG.

Comment: Thanks but even with this i need to use a cookie, not sure how to get it working with just basic_auth

Comment: Why do you need to use a cookie?

Comment: Please see above code which I'm running against a local dockerised container of airflow v263